# Issues with MobileVLCKit on iOS (Nightly Build)

Tags: ios, swift, vlc, libvlc

I have some issues I can't get around with MobileVLCKit on iOS (MobileVLCKit-UniversalBinary-20160204-0547). I am on iOS9 and Swift.

- I need to be able to know when a stream cannot be played, either because the url is not valid or for any other reason. I tried checking `VLCMediaPlayer.state` but it won't (ever) be `VLCMediaPlayerStateError` so I can present some sort of user friendly error. Any workarounds?
- `VLCMediaPlayerStateBuffering` is kind of useless. The state is getting set to `VLCMediaPlayerStateBuffering` when the player is buffering the remote media but doesn't switch to some other state, preferably `VLCMediaPlayerStatePlaying` when it plays smoothly. Effectively, I cannot show a loading spinner or something when the video is buffering.
- When the remote video stops or the streaming stops working mid-streaming, the `drawable` view of `VLCMediaPlayer` always displays the last frame. Is there any way to sort of purge/clear the drawable view?

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for checking out our unstable nightly builds :)

- This is on my TODO list for next week. We will add a proper dialog API including support for user friendly dialogs (customizable by the app). If you have specific test cases where VLCMediaPlayerStateError fail to be send, we'd love to have them.
- True, VLCMediaPlayerStateBuffering is send only when buffering starts. However, you should receive state change events which give you the opportunity to check whether VLC still buffers or not. At least, that's the way we implemented the "Buffering" spinner in VLC's iOS and tvOS apps.
- No, there is no way to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your, as always, prompt answer. It could be the nightly build itself, but `VLCMediaPlayerStateError` is not being sent ever. I guess if you try setting a `VLCMedia` with a non-existent url you will see it yourself. 

Again, it could be the nightly build, but the last state change is always `VLCMediaPLayerStateBuffering`. Even if the video is playing smoothly..

Comment: Interesting. I'll have a look!

Comment: Any update on this? Facing same issue with 2.7 stable prod version... It always stating the status is buffering, even if video starts playing.

Comment: @feepk iOS VLCMobileKit does not play RTSP video. It says VLC is unable to open the MRL. Please help

Comment: @Dhiraj Das: Please open a new question or post a log with more details on https://forum.videolan.org